# utilizar dois merges matched then no sql server server

Tags: sql-server, merge

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para utilizar o segundo merge matched then

Eu preciso do seguinte caso, sabendo que o source é um log, não acontecerá o "WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN"

```
MERGE tabelaTarget AS target  
USING 
   (SELECT id, codigo, flag_deletado from tabelaSource) AS source 
ON (target.ID = source.ID and target.flag_deletado = '')  
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.codigo <> source.codigo and source.flag_deletado = '') THEN
   UPDATE SET target.codigo= source.codigo
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET target.flag_deletado = '*'

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  

        INSERT (codigo, flag_deletado)  
        VALUES (source.codigo, flag_deletado='')  
 OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO tabelaLog;
```

Na documentação diz o seguinte:

"A instrução MERGE pode ter, no máximo, duas cláusulas WHEN MATCHED. Se duas cláusulas forem especificadas, a primeira deverá ser acompanhada de uma cláusula AND . Para qualquer linha especificada, a segunda cláusula WHEN MATCHED será aplicada somente se a primeira não for. Se houver duas cláusulas WHEN MATCHED, uma delas deverá especificar uma ação UPDATE e a outra, uma ação DELETE. Quando UPDATE for especificada na cláusula  e mais de uma linha de  corresponder a uma linha em target_table com base em , SQL Server retornará um erro. A instrução MERGE não pode atualizar a mesma linha mais de uma vez, nem atualizar e excluir a mesma linha."

**Entendo que se a primeira tiver o AND a segundo caso deveria acontecer normalmente como escrevi no script. Porem na Doc também, existe a sintaxe que eu não consegui entender.**

Entendo que se a primeira tiver o AND a segundo caso deveria acontecer normalmente como escrevi no script. Porem na Doc também, existe a sintaxe que eu não consegui entender.

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [,...n] ]  
MERGE
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ]
    [ INTO ] <target_table> [ WITH ( <merge_hint> ) ] [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    USING <table_source>
    ON <merge_search_condition>  
    [ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_not_matched> ]  
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [ AND <clause_search_condition> ]  
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]  
    [ <output_clause> ]  
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ];

<merge_matched>::=  
    { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }
```

Como eu coloco esses blocos juntos? Vejo que tem ; Como chamo o merge_matched, não entendi mesmo, eu não posso usar o deleted, pq o banco de dados que estou trazendo, não é normalizado, isso pode dar vários problemas no meu banco de dados a direita que é normalizado.

Comment: Mas qual é o objetivo da consulta? Explique o contexto para facilitar as sugestões.

Comment: José Diz, o objetivo é a tabela de destino ser atualizada por uma tabela de log de origem, pois, a tabela de fato de origem, se eu fosse fazer merge com ela, demoraria horas, são milhões (quase bilhão) de registros.

Estou pensando em colocar os dados em uma tabela temporária, primeiro eu faço o merge, com o retorno também da flag do excluidos, faço o update na tabela de destino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi dessa maneira

```
MERGE tabelaTarget AS target  
USING 
   (SELECT id, codigo, flag_deletado from tabelaSource) AS source 
ON (target.ID = source.ID and target.flag_deletado = '')  
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.codigo <> source.codigo 
   or source.flag_deletado = '*') THEN --colocado o or e flag_deletado = '*'

  UPDATE SET target.codigo = iif(source.flag_deletado = '*', target.codigo ,source.codigo,
   target.flag_deletado = iif(source.flag_deletado = '*', target.flag_deletado, )
--foi utilizado o iif para resolver a duplicidade do matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN     
   INSERT (codigo, flag_deletado)  
   VALUES (source.codigo, flag_deletado='')  
 OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO tabelaLog
```

;